# On my mac. whereis command failed return application path

Tags: oh-my-zsh, zshrc

All

1. my shell is oh-my-zsh.
2. “whereis” doesn't work, there is not any response while I'v executed the command.
3. “which” works normally.

> Here are some details

```
~ ⌚ 3:26:26
$ echo $PATH      ‹ruby-2.2.4›
/Users/luoweiguang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/Users/luoweiguang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/Users/luoweiguang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/luoweiguang/.rvm/bin

~ ⌚ 3:26:28
$ which man      ‹ruby-2.2.4›
/usr/bin/man

~ ⌚ 3:26:36
$ whereis Notes      ‹ruby-2.2.4›

~ ⌚ 3:26:49
$ whereis XCode      ‹ruby-2.2.4›

~ ⌚ 3:41:35
$
```

*I spent much time on the problem for these days. and I didn't find a way to fix it, Hope you guys can help me. Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereis` probably works just fine, there are just no binaries named `Notes` or `XCode` in your `$PATH`. For confirmation, please try to run `which Notes` and `which XCode`. Also try `whereis man` to confirm that `whereis` is actually working.

`XCode` and `Notes` come as App bundle and their executables are not placed in the "normal" places like `/usr/bin`. Instead their executable is inside their bundle directory, which (or rather the appropriate subdirectory) is usually not part of `$PATH`. For `Notes` this the bundle directory is `/Applications/Notes.app` and the executable is `/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes`.

Comment: According to your advice. I've tested the command of "whereis" it do works normal as same as "which". thanks. Is there any simple terminal command can help me quickly to locate a App's path?

Comment: Yes - `which` ;)

Comment: @jena not really. As noted, `which` (just like ` whereis`) will only list executables in directories, which are listed in `$PATH`. This is usually not the case for app bundles.

Comment: oh I didn't know your usage of "App" was a strictly technical term, my bad.. I use mac only at work (luckily)